# how to run factor file from command line in windows os 7?

Tags: windows

the factor file is: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.factor`

```
"Hello, world" print
```

then how can I run it from command line, I have factor installed, the factor.exe and factor.com is in $PATH.

I do not want to start the factor ui, just want to run this file and print the output to stdout.

I have tested with `fator.exe -run test.factor` and the factor file is:

```
USE: io
IN: hello-world

: hello ( -- ) "Hello world" print ;

MAIN: hello
```

but nothing print to the stdout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, with a script *test.factor*, you call :

**factor -run test.factor**

```
USE: io
IN: hello-world

: hello ( -- ) "Hello world" print ;

MAIN: hello
```

output :

*Hello world*

Comment: You wrote "factor.exe"  : it is **factor.com**